# How do I do a grow and shrink counter in Jquery and HTML?

Tags: html, jquery, counter

I want to try and make a circle grow from 20px to 300px. It is supposed to only enlarge just to reduce back down in size. There is a button meant to be clicked to start the action. Every time the button is clicked, it is supposed to add one to the counter that says "Grow and Shrink Counter:".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      height: '300px',
      width: '300px'
    });
    $("div").animate({
      height: '20px',
      width: '20px'
    });
  });
});

let counter = 0

document.querySelector("#counter").addEventListener('click', function() {
  counter++
  this.innerHTML = counter
})
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#shrink {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

#container1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 75%;
}

#grow {
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#counter {
  text: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1">
  <button id="grow"><span style="font-size:20px">Grow</span> and <span style="font-size:8px">Shrink</span></button>
  <p id="counter">Grow and Shrink Counter:</p>
</div>
<div id="container2">
  <div id="shrink"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few mistakes I could find right off the bat:

1. In your html, there are no opening and closing quotes for the `id`s
2. `counter` variable is declared twice. You can name the counter button variable to something like `counterButton`
3. In the code snippet, include `jQuery` library